# Why does 'X-Auth-Token' get updated with every request/response?

Tags: spring-boot, session, redis, xauth

I'm using **spring-boot** + **OAuth2** with **Redis** managing sessions. I would save some data in one request and retrieve the data in another. And I use the `X-Auth-Token` header to identify sessions, as shown below:

```java
@Bean
public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
    return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
}
```

I noticed that I got a new `X-Auth-Token` with every response and I have to use the new one (from the response, instead of the one that I used in the request) to be able to access the session data.

Screenshot from postman:
[image]

This seems quite unnecessary (does this mean that data is being moved around in Redis all the time?), and I wonder if there are settings that I can use to just use one `X-Auth-Token` instead.

Comment: Do you find the solution?

Comment: I can't remember exactly the solution (not a perfect one either): it seems to have something to do with `SessionCreationPolicy`. You can try to set it to `IF_REQUIRED` (by default it's `NEVER`) in your configuration:
  `public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {`
    `http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(
      SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED`
    `);`